# Select where column1 or column2 equal to id, but group by other value of the row

Tags: mysql

I have this table for messages between users

```
id |sender |receiver 
--------------------
   |1      |2
   |3      |1
   |1      |4
   |2      |1
```

I want to select all rows where t.sender OR t.receiver is equal to 1 (user for which i am searching messages), but to group by other values of the row (Group by other users).

In this example result for user1 should contain 3 rows grouped by  user2, user3 and user4 values.

Comment: It depends on how you want to group.  If you want to group before searching, use a having clause, otherwise if you want to group only based on the results having either a 1 in sender or receiver then use a where clause (possibly as a subquery).

Comment: what does `grouped by user2, user3, user4 values` mean ? u mean order by?

Comment: i want to get users which messaged to user 1 or been messaged by user 1. In this example, i want only 3 rows with column name, say it "target" with values 2, 3 and 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to fetch them using `union all`.First you need fetch messages sent by the user and union those results with the messages received by the same user.

```
select receiver, count(1), 'Sending' from messages where sender = 1 group by receiver
union all
select sender, count(1), 'Receiving' from messages where receiver = 1 group by sender
```

Comment: But this will return two rows for user 2, isnt it?